# Why does React Native BottomTabNavigator re-render child1 (which uses only stateA) when child2 (uses only stateB) calls setStateB and how to avoid?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I notice that when I go to the AwayScreen and change the value of stateB by calling setStateB, the HomeScreen re-renders, even though the HomeScreen uses only stateA and the AwayScreen uses only StateB.

This only happens after I have clicked on the HomeScreen for the first time (i.e. only after its first render)

Finally, I notice the AboutScreen child never re-renders when the parent tab navigator re-renders, which is good and suggests children don't re-render just because the parent re-rendered.

I would like the HomeScreen to NOT re-render just because the AwayScreen has called setStateB. Is this possible? If so, how?

I have the following code in App.tsx:

```
console.log("Starting app");

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const MyTabs = () => {
console.log("Tabs are rendering");

const [stateA, setStateA] = useState<number>(0);
const [stateB, setStateB] = useState<number>(0);

return (
        <Tabs.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, size }) => {
                    let iconName;
                    if (route.name === "Home") {
                        iconName = focused ? "home" : "home-outline";
                    } else if (route.name === "Away") {
                        iconName = focused ? "away" : "away-outline";
                    } else if (route.name === "Scan") {
                        iconName = focused
                            ? "bluetooth"
                            : "bluetooth-outline";
                    } else if (route.name === "About") {
                        iconName = focused ? "flower" : "flower-outline";
                    }
                    return (
                        <Ionicons
                            name={iconName}
                            size={size}
                        />
                    );
                },
            })}
            initialRouteName="Scan">
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Scan"
                children={props => (
                    <ScanScreen
                        setStateA={setStateA}
                        {...props}
                    />
                )}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Home"
                children={props => (
                    <HomeScreen
                        stateA={stateA}
                        {...props}
                    />
                )}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="Away"
                children={props => (
                    <AwayScreen
                        stateB={stateB}
                        setStateB={setStateB}
                        {...props}
                    />
                )}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="About"  
                component={AboutScreen}
            />
        </Tabs.Navigator>
   );
};

const App = () => {
console.log(" ");
console.log("Top of App - rendering");

return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <View style={globalStyles.navigationContainer}>
            <MyTabs />
        </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Experiment 1: I start on ScanScreen, click on AwayScreen and there it changes the value of stateB by calling setStateB when I click on a slider

The LOG output looks like the following if I never click on HomeScreen:

```
LOG  Starting app
LOG  Running "test_app" with {"rootTag":71}

LOG  Top of App - rendering 
LOG  Tabs are rendering
LOG  ScanScreen rendering

LOG  AwayScreen rendering

LOG  Tabs are rendering
LOG  ScanScreen rendering
LOG  AwayScreen rendering
```

Experiment 2:  I start on ScanScreen, click on HomeScreen (it just displays stateA) then click on AwayScreen and there I change the value of stateB. I see that HomeScreen re-renders after I click on the slider on the AwayScreen to setStateB:

```
LOG  Starting app
LOG  Running "test_app" with {"rootTag":71}

LOG  Top of App - rendering
LOG  Tabs are rendering
LOG  ScanScreen rendering

LOG  HomeScreen rendering
LOG  AwayScreen rendering

LOG  Tabs are rendering
LOG  ScanScreen rendering
LOG  HomeScreen rendering
LOG  AwayScreen rendering
```